# Customize QCompleter with QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to enable wildcard matching for `QLineEdit` and `QCompleter`. If the string model is `['abc', 'cba']`, when I type `ab*` or `a*`, it should display `abc`. Below is the code I wrote, but it still behaves like a regular match. Any idea how I should fix it?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys, random


class MyCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
        super().setModel(self.proxyModel)

    def updatePattern(self, patternStr):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterWildcard(patternStr)


class MyMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        model = QStringListModel(['abc', 'cba'])

        completer = MyCompleter()
        completer.setModel(model)

        searchBar = QLineEdit(self)
        searchBar.setCompleter(completer)
        searchBar.textChanged.connect(lambda wildcard: completer.updatePattern(wildcard))

        vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vLayout.addWidget(searchBar, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(vLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mm = MyMain()
    mm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class LineEdit(QLineEdit):                                     # +++
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.multipleCompleter = None

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        QLineEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
        if not self.multipleCompleter:
            return
        c = self.multipleCompleter

        if self.text() == "":                                    
            return
        c.setCompletionPrefix(self.cursorWord(self.text()))      

        if len(c.completionPrefix()) < 1:
            c.popup().hide()
            return
        c.complete()

    def cursorWord(self, sentence):
        p = sentence.rfind(" ")
        if p == -1:
            return sentence
        return sentence[p + 1:]

    def insertCompletion(self, text):                             
        p = self.text().rfind(" ")                                
        if p == -1:
            self.setText(text)                                    
        else:
            self.setText(self.text()[:p+1]+ text)           

    def setMultipleCompleter(self, completer):
        self.multipleCompleter = completer
        self.multipleCompleter.setWidget(self)
        completer.activated.connect(self.insertCompletion)


class MyCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def setModel(self, model):
        self.proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
        super().setModel(self.proxyModel)

    def updatePattern(self, patternStr):
        print(f"patternStr-> {patternStr}")
        self.proxyModel.setFilterWildcard(patternStr)


class MyMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        model = QStringListModel(['abc', 'cba'])

        completer = MyCompleter()
        completer.setModel(model)

#        searchBar = QLineEdit(self)
#        searchBar.setCompleter(completer)
#        searchBar.textChanged.connect(lambda wildcard: completer.updatePattern(wildcard))

        searchBar = LineEdit(self)                              # +++
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)        # +++
        searchBar.setMultipleCompleter(completer)               # +++

        vLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vLayout.addWidget(searchBar, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(vLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mm = MyMain()
    mm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But this is not what I am trying to implement. When I type `ab*`, it should match the word `abc` and display it.

Comment: @Einiemand Sorry, I don't quite understand you. And what should be if you typed `a` or `ab` or `abc` ? and why recruit  `*` ?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. `*` is part of the wildcard matching. Like when you use git, you can do `git add *.py` to add all files whose names end with `.py`. And in my code, I want to display a word as long as `QRegExp(pattern, Qt.CaseInsensitive, QRegExp.Wildcard).match(<word>)` returns `True`. And since neither `a` nor `ab` match `abc`, the word wouldn't be displayed.

Comment: @Einiemand  What you wrote should be reflected in the question. And I do not see in your example of using  `QRegExp` ?

Comment: That's true. My point is that the input is the pattern, and the GUI should display all words that match the pattern.